# Указатель на массив строк char в Borland C++ Builder 6. Как изменить какой либо элемент?

Tags: c++, указатели, char, borland-c++

Подскажите пожалуйста есть указатель на массив строк char например такой:

```
char* test[] = {{"test1"},{"test2"},{"test3"}};
```

Как в этом массиве я могу изменить к примеру второй элемент(который содержит test2).

Сейчас нашёл только вариант через создание указателя на адрес элемента массива и посимвольное изменение с использованием нового созданного указателя, то есть так:

```
char *ptr;
ptr = &*test[1];
ptr[0] = 'A';//Изменение первого символа в массиве и так далее нужное количество букв
```

Comment: `test[1][0] = 'A';`.

Comment: `&*` cхлопываются в ничего. В итоге остается просто `test[1][0] = 'A';`. Но! Я не знаю, как в borland C++, но в совеременном С++ строковые литералы (т.е. константные строки в кавычках) менять нельзя, а ваш код вообще не скомпилируется, потому что не подписали `const`.

Comment: В паре `&*` смысла почти нет.

Comment: Благодарю за предложенный вариант, а можно ли как то сразу нужною строку присвоить, то есть записью вроде что-то = "ABCD"; или что-то = {"ABCD"};

Comment: Совет: borland C++ в помойку, ставьте нормальный компилятор (на выбор: Clang, GCC, MSVC). Сырые указатели тоже в мусор: `std::string test[] = {"test1","test2","test3"}; test[1] = "foo";`. Тогда все будет работать как надо.

Comment: Пока что советом по выбрасыванию Borland C++ не воспользуюсь. И в перспективе что не факт, он нормальный, мне нужно пару моментов по нему прояснить. Вариант с string не годится.

Comment: *"Вариант с string не годится."* Почему нет? *"он нормальный"* Мне кажется у вас еще недостаточно опыта, чтобы определить, нормальный он или нет. Он очень старый (последняя версия в 2000 году?), и в реальной работе его вряд ли кто-то использует. Рано или поздно вам придется переучиваться, и лучше начать раньше. Современные компиляторы следуют единому стандарту, поэтому нет большой разницы, какой из них брать. А у borland'а, если правильно помню, какой-то свой странный старый диалект С++.

Comment: Для решения поставленных задач мне нужно понимать не так много моментов на c++. Я понимаю что язык изменился и многое из того что ранее делалось вручную - автоматизировано. При этом я планирую изучать Borland c++ 6. Много лет программирую на php, так же опыт с JS nodeJS, Delphi, Basic. В общем изучаю именно Borland C+ builder 6.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, присвоить какую либо другую строку указанному массиву можно используя следующий код:

```
&*test[1] = "ABCD";
```

Участников обсуждения в комментариях благодарю, их варианты приведённого кода натолкнули на размышления которые привели к перебору вариантов и нахождению требуемого для поставленной задачи.

Comment: Это то же самое, что и просто `test[1] = ...`.